# How to capture all selected items in a Multiselect option list and bundle using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, multi-select, blur, focusout

I want to write all multi-selected option items to a server-side database table via Ajax. I do not want to call the function and write on each select/deselect action. I want to let the user select and deselect all the desired option items and then I want to make the ajax call and write the results once to the database.

I want to handle this in jQuery.

I've got the Ajax script and server-side DB update script working -- no problem.

What is the best way to capture the multi-select items and make the ajax call?

Would it be when focus leaves the select box? Or some other, better method?

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

**Amendment #1**

It is looking like `.change()` is the only way to go here...with the exception, of course, adding a button as is suggested in the answers. The button option is not the way I wish to go with the app. I can't seem to capture `.focus()` or `.blur()` or `.focusout()` on my `<select>` element.

**Amendment #2**

Tried this -- does not work

```
  $( 'select.driverItems' ).on('blur',function(){
    alert('focused out');
    console.log( $(this).val() );
  });
```

Tried this -- does not work

```
  $( 'select#driverIDs_0' ).on('blur',function(){
    alert('focused out');
    console.log( $(this).val() );
  });
```

Tried this -- it works !!

```
  $( 'select.driverItems' ).change(function() {
    alert('focused out');
    console.log( $(this).val() );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Techincally, there's no way to know for sure that a user is done with a multiselect, as there are other factors where the user will leave the selection process,(filling up other fields, alt-tab, selecting messages to read, etc.) firing the lost-focus event.

As much as possible, you don't want a lot of round-trips to the server as well, so you have a good idea not to update on select/deselect.

Only plausible way to do it without having unwanted results would be to add a button that fires the ajax.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan. [Part 1] Is there such a thing in jQuery as "`.lostFocusEvent()`" that I can try? I am implementing now using `.on('change',...)` but I rather not hit the server on every mouse click. I will, however, hit the server on every mouse click if my only solution is to add another button. From a usability standpoint, my client will freak with having to click a submit button because the web form is already so complex and contains dozens of data collection points.

Comment: [Part 2] I need to implement 3 separate `.focusout()` instances for sending multiselect values back to the server so I am not interested to marry them with 3 additional submit buttons. Thanks.

Comment: @H.Ferrence yes, you can use the `.on('blur', function(evt, args){...} )` https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: For whatever reason @Nathan, I tried it yesterday (before you suggested) and it did not work. I tried it again today and still -- no success...`$( 'select#myId' ).on('blur',function(){...});`

Comment: Did you try just using the id in the selector instead of an inheritance selector? based on my understanding `$('select #myId')` will only search your  id inside the `<select>` tag instead of the `<select>` tag itself

Comment: See my amendment in the OQ @Nathan. Thank you for helping me here !!

Answer (score 0):

- Then let the user select whatever he wants
- Add a button in Html
- And when the the button is pressed
- Get all the selected value in jquery
- And make an Ajax call and save the values

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. I prefer to do it the way I describe because I have 3 different selection options side-by-side and I do not want to add more buttons. I am looking at `focusout()` as a possible solutions. Not sure if that ends up being the best, but I am trying it out nonetheless.